# Finding the max number <= some other number

Tags: python, list

I have a list `L` containing sorted numbers.

I have a number `x`, arbitrary. I wish to find the largest number from `L` that is `<= x`. I can do this with a loop but curious if there is a Pythonic one-liner or fancy function for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module. The complexity of this approach is `O(LogN)` compared to a simple loop which is `O(N)`.

```
>>> import bisect
def solve(lis, item):
     ind = bisect.bisect_right(lis, item, hi = len(lis)-1)
     return lis[ind] if lis[ind] <= item else lis[ind-1]

>>> L = range(10, 100)
>>> L.remove(15)       
>>> solve(L,15)
14
>>> solve(L,17)
17
>>> L.pop(20)
31
>>> solve(L,31)
30
```

Comment: Code works but solve(lis,item) should probably be solve(L,item) or the rest should show lis, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest you can do this is to use [`bisect.bisect_left`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left):

```
>>> r = range(300)
>>> import bisect
>>> r[bisect.bisect_left(r,280)]
280
```

This results in an algorithm which takes O(log(N)) operations (on average) whereas the straight loop will take O(N) operations on average.

To avoid an `IndexError` at the top end of the range, you can set the `hi` keyword:

```
>>> r[bisect.bisect_right(r,320,hi=len(r)-1)]
299
```

Comment: The OP said his list `L` is sorted.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> max([x for x in [1,3,5,7,9] if x <= 5])
5
```

Comment: This is slow since op's list is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I saw an answer inspired from functional programming, but it was deleted, so I'm going to post something similar:

```
>>> import functools
>>> L = [1, 3, 15]
>>> x = 10
>>> functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a if b > x else max(a,b), L)
>>> 3
```

Please note that the `bisect` solution shown by the others is more efficient on sorted lists, however if the list is not sorted this is as efficient as a normal `for` loop (or as efficient as [dav's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17283354/770023)), since the complexity is O(n).

This example is here only to show some functional programming concepts in python.